# Incompatible integer to pointer conversion? what?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am reading a txt file that was encoded with UTF8.

I am now reading the file. I have this lines:

```
- (NSString *) readFromFile {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/textfile.txt",
                          documentsDirectory];
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName
                        usedEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                        error:nil];
}
```

I have this error on the last line:

**incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending int to parameter of type NSUTF8StringEncoding ***

why?

Comment: I have added the full method

Comment: The first thing you do when there's such an issue is to check the signature and parameters. You are passing `int` where `NSStringEncoding *` is expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key here is the "d" in "use**d**Encoding".

That parameter serves to pass information back to the caller about the encoding *used* to read the file.

This means that it is the `NSString` class that informs the caller which encoding it used to create the object from the raw data in the file - and *not* the caller that can instruct the class about which encoding to employ.

To get this information, you need to declare a variable and pass a reference to it so the `NSString` class object can put the information into it for you to read later if you need the information.

```
NSStringEncoding enc;

NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName
                    usedEncoding: &enc
                    error:nil];

// Do something with the information about the encoding used
if ( enc == NSUTF8StringEncoding ) {
     // ...
}

return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

use:
`initWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:`

Answer (score 1):

```
initWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:
Returns an NSString object initialized by reading data from the file at a given path and returns by reference the encoding used to interpret the characters.

- (id)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path usedEncoding:(NSStringEncoding *)enc error:(NSError **)error
Parameters
path
A path to a file.
enc
Upon return, if the file is read successfully, contains the encoding used to interpret the file at path.
error
If an error occurs, upon returns contains an NSError object that describes the problem. If you are not interested in possible errors, pass in NULL.
```

This is from the documentation :-)

So basically, like @Monolo did say, this is used to return to you the encoding type and not set it.
If you want to set it you have to use: 
`- (id)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error`