# Google Api error "Multiple methods named 'initWithArray:' found"

Tags: objective-c, swift, api, google-api, xcode7

I am using the google calendar api and I am getting two errors.

1. GTMGatherInputStream.m:25:13: Multiple methods named 'initWithArray:' found

   ```
   #import "GTMGatherInputStream.h"
   @implementation GTMGatherInputStream
   + (NSInputStream *)streamWithArray:(NSArray *)dataArray {
       return [[[self alloc] initWithArray:dataArray] autorelease]; //error on this line
   }
   ```
2. GTMOAuth2Authentication.h:31:11: 'GTMSessionFetcher.h' file not found

   ```
   #if GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER
   #import "GTMSessionFetcher.h" //GTMSessionFetcher.h file not found error
   #else
   #import "GTMHTTPFetcher.h"
   #endif  // GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER
   ```

I have researched the error everywhere online and I have found nothing. I am running GM El capitan with GM Xcode 7.0. I Have tried multiple different ways on solving it and nothing has worked. My code will not compile. How do I fix this?

Comment: Just installed Xcode 7 update, and I'm having the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: The same issue for me. Have to use Xcode 6.4 to do the build.(build for Mac)

Answer (score 15):

I assume Google is going to implement a fix for this in the near future; in the meantime, we can do a couple of hacks to get around those issues:

1. change `return [[[self alloc] initWithArray:dataArray] autorelease];`

   to

   `return [[(GTMGatherInputStream*)[self alloc] initWithArray:dataArray] autorelease];`
2. change

   ```
   #ifndef GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER
   #define GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER 1
   #endif
   ```

   to

   ```
   #ifndef GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER
   #define GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER 0
   #endif
   ```

I had to do this in two places where `GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER` was defined.

One final thing, was to go to the GTL project build settings, and set Apple LLVM 7.0 warnings `Deprecated Functions` to NO. With these 3 steps the Calendar API compiles successfully on iOS9.

Comment: I did all of those steps and I got this new error: "google-api-objectivec-client/Source/HTTPFetcher/GTMHTTPFetcherLogging.m:793:59: 'stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use -stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters: instead, which always uses the recommended UTF-8 encoding, and which encodes for a specific URL component or subcomponent since each URL component or subcomponent has different rules for what characters are valid."                         I have looked into the error and have nothing. Any help?

Comment: Change the line with stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding to:
`NSString *escapedResponseFile = [responseDataFileName stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];`

Comment: Did you go to the GTL project build settings, and set Apple LLVM 7.0 warnings Deprecated Functions to NO? That step fixed the deprecation warnings for me.

Comment: I did both of those now I have this:google-api-objectivec-client/Source/HTTPFetcher/GTMHTTPFetcherLogging.m:797:112: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'NSStringEncoding' (aka 'unsigned long') to parameter of type 'NSCharacterSet * _Nonnull'          I have tried all NSStringEncoding with ints in them but none of them worked. this I really don't get. help?

Comment: Fixed now this: google-api-objectivec-client/Source/HTTPFetcher/GTMHTTPFetcherLogging.m:797:112: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'NSStringEncoding' (aka 'unsigned long') to parameter of type 'NSCharacterSet * _Nonnull'         I have tried every NSStringEncoding with a Int in it and none of them worked. help?

Comment: Does this question help with your last error? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750251/incompatible-integer-to-pointer-conversion-what

Answer (score 0):

I also had to deal with an error `Comparison of address of ... not equal to null pointer is always true`

This was causing the app not to build. Had to modify lines 340 and 1088 of GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.m

E.g.,

```
  // CGP; 9/30/15; took out "&" before kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly
  //if (accessibility == NULL
  //    && &kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly != NULL) {
  if (accessibility == NULL
        && kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly != NULL) {
    accessibility = kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change self in `[[[self alloc] initWithArray:dataArray] autorelease]` to `GTMGatherInputStream`. It's working for me:

```
#import "GTMGatherInputStream.h"
@implementation GTMGatherInputStream
+ (NSInputStream *)streamWithArray:(NSArray *)dataArray {
    return [[[GTMGatherInputStream alloc] initWithArray:dataArray] autorelease];
}
```