# Use google GTL lib with iOS 9

Tags: ios, iphone, google-drive-api, ios9

i have a project that use GTL lib (i integrate the GTL project into mine, not the compiled lib).

now i want to compile using iOS 9, but the project do not compile anymore (allot of deprecated functions).

i can't found any compilable codes in google repositories.

could anyone give me a solution, thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the errors?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615688/google-api-error-multiple-methods-named-initwitharray-found

Comment: @Red Mak do you have any solution? , I am facing same problem right now...I didn't find any type of solution, I implement new GTLCore frame wrok with this link https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart but it gives many error in my old coding....