# GTMSessionFetcher.h file not found upgrading app to latest google-api-objectivec-client

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-drive-api, ios9

I implement access to Google Drive in my iOS app. This has been an active feature in the app since middle of 2014 and functions properly under iOS 6, 7 & 8. I am currently checking my project for compatibility with iOS 9.

I've downloaded the latest `google-api-objectivec-client` to ensure my project remains up to date.

I redid the standard Google implementation... as detailed in [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart) and included for completeness at the end of this post.

**Problem: When I attempt to build in any of my releases I receive the error "`GTMSessionFetcher.h` file not found".**

I'm certain I've implemented the API properly as per the steps below / on the Google web page.

I've looked through older versions of my code but unfortunately I did not back up the Google SDK, so cannot easily tell what has changed.

It seems to stem from this... within `GTMOAuth2Authentication.h`...

```
#if GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER
  #import "GTMSessionFetcher.h"
#else
  #import "GTMHTTPFetcher.h"
#endif  // GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER
```

I dont understand how `GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER` is set and why it would be true in this instance.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

---

**Google Drive API Implementation for iOS**

*Note: Steps 1 & 2 complete without issue.*

Step 3: Prepare the project

1. In Xcode, create a new project to contain the sample app:

   - Click File > New > Project, select the Single View Application template, and click Next.
   - Fill in the Product Name, Organization Name, and Company Identifier. Make sure to select Objective-C as the Language, and then click Next.
   - Select a destination directory for the project and click Create.
2. Add the client library by dragging `GTL.xcodeproj` from the `Source` directory of the client library download folder above into the XCode project.
3. In the XCode Project Navigator, select the project you created to reveal the project settings.
4. Select the Build Phases tab in the project settings and modify the `Link Binary with Libraries` list to include:

   - `libGTLTouchStaticLib.a` from the GTL project.
   - `Security.framework` and `SystemConfiguration.framework`.
5. Select the Build Settings tab in the project settings and modify the following two build settings:

   - Add `-ObjC -all_load` to the Linking > Other Linker Flags setting. A good way to edit these fields is to click once on the field name to select it, then click Enter to input the setting.
   - Add the client library headers to the application project by adding the Source directory of the client library to the Search Paths > User headers search path section with the recursive option. You can select the recursive option either by appending ** to the path or by double-clicking the entered path and selecting recursive in the dialog that appears.
     To find the absolute path to this directory in a Unix-based system, navigate a terminal window to the directory where you downloaded the client library in Step 2, cd into the Source directory, and type the pwd command.
6. Drag `GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib` from client library's `Source/OAuth2/Touch` folder into the app's `Supporting Files` folder.
7. Add the Drive API service by dragging `GTLDrive.h` and `GTLDrive_Sources.m` from the client library's `Source/Services/Drive/Generated` folder directly to the application project.

Comment: Have you checked out this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615688/google-api-error-multiple-methods-named-initwitharray-found

Comment: No I have not but that looks promising thanks Rivero

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks initially to [Rivero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4151216/rivero) for pointing me in the right direction...

Thanks to [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1176247/peter) for his answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615688/google-api-error-multiple-methods-named-initwitharray-found).

Building for iOS 6, 7, 8 & 9...

Hacked the following...

---

**STEP 1**

In `GTMOAuth2Authentication.h` (OAuth directory) and in  `GTLService.h` (Objects directory)

find this code block...

```
#if (!TARGET_OS_IPHONE && defined(MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_11) && MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_11) \
  || (TARGET_OS_IPHONE && defined(__IPHONE_9_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_9_0)
  #ifndef GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER
    #define GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER 1
  #endif
#endif
```

... and change

```
#define GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER 1
```

... to

```
#define GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER 0
```

---

**STEP 2**

In `GTMGatherInputStream.m` (HTTPFetcher directory)

... change

```
return [[[self alloc] initWithArray:dataArray] autorelease];
```

... to

```
return [[(GTMGatherInputStream*)[self alloc] initWithArray:dataArray] autorelease];
```

---

**STEP 3**

In `GTMHTTPFetcherLogging.m` (HTTPFetcher directory)

... change

```
NSString *escapedResponseFile = [responseDataFileName stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

... to

```
NSString *escapedResponseFile = [responseDataFileName stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

---

**STEP 4**

In `GTL` project settings, under Apple LLVM 7.0 Warnings - All Languages

... change

Deprecated Functions = YES

... to

Deprecated Functions = NO

---

Comment: I want to post this link for anyone still confused by the fact that as of now the quickstart tutorial references files that don't exist. https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/issues/127

Comment: @andrewbuilder Thanks... You solved my problem +1 from my side......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35666872/use-google-drive-gtl-lib-with-ios-9-and-xcode7-and-above-version

Comment: @andrewbuilder Now I am able to run my project without error.., but problem is it not loading google sing in page...Is there any other settings?

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD the solution description is complete for any generic implementation. Check the Google related code in your presenting view controllers - it may need to be updated. Otherwise ask a new question and include the link in these comments...

Comment: I don't have the code block mentioned in step 1 in my GTMOAuth2Authentication.h file. Any thoughts on that matter?

Comment: @fischgeek sorry no. Any thoughts are just guesses. Might be that Google has updated the API and it's no longer necessary for new builds? But as noted, just guessing

Answer (score 5):

@andrewbuilder's solution works.

If your target is IOS 8, just change

```
#define GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER 1
```

to

```
#define GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER 0
```

in both GTMOAuth2Authentication.h and GTLService.h files.

If your target is IOS 9, you need to replace the GTMHTTPFetcher file with GTMSessionFetcher file (https://code.google.com/p/gtm-session-fetcher/).

Reference: https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/issues/88

Answer (score 1):

Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C using JSON-RFC has been replaced with REST (no end date released yet).

[image]

Pulling the new library with all dependencies worked for me with no hacking what so ever.

https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest.git
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue.This is the way how I managed to solve this.

Documentation says that we should put absolute path in **User Header Search Paths**.I was putting absolute path but my directory name contained spaces which was not understood correctly by Xcode.My Directory was

```
/Users/maclover/Xcode Test Projects/Manager/gtm-session-fetcher/Source/
```

Then I changed to directory which didnot contain any spaces like

```
/Users/maclover/Desktop/Manager/gtm-session-fetcher/Source/
```

Changing this in **User Header Search Paths** in my application and **GTLTouchStaticLib** worked for me.Do same for objective C client path as well.

**Last thing there is no need for `#define GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER 1` changed to `#define GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER 0` if you are using latest projects.It was workaround for previous library and google has updated it now on November 10.**

Comment: Thanks for the advice, appreciated, however I have no spaces in my **user header search path** directory path strings.

Answer (score 0):

After numerous trials and errors, i stumbled upon a forum post saying that  Google has been focusing its efforts on the pod version of the API client.

Use:

> pod 'GoogleAPIClient'

link source: [GoogleApiClient](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/issues/199)

Answer (score 0):

I have that problem after update Firebase. I try many ways but only this one worked for me. Reinstall Pods by running following commands:
`pod deintegrate`
`pod install`

Answer (score -1):

STEP 1

GTMOAuth2Authentication.h

```
#define GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER 1  to #define GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER 0
```

STEP 2

GTMGatherInputStream.m

```
 return [[[self alloc] initWithArray:dataArray] autorelease];
  ... to 
 return [[(GTMGatherInputStream*)[self alloc] initWithArray:dataArray] autorelease];
```

STEP 3
[like image: ios version choose less than ios 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV7Yq.jpg)

STEP 4 [enable bitCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuBes.jpg)