# Google Drive iOS Configuration - Stuck

Tags: google-drive-api

I am following the iOS QuickStart for the Google Drive iOS SDK and I am stuck at step 3-d. "Select the "GTL" project's "GTLTouchStaticLib" target"

When I select the GTLCore project and view the targets, the GTLTouchStaticLib target is not listed, as shown, so I cannot proceed.  Please advise...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did some research regarding GTL library and found out that both GTMOAuth2Authentication.h and GTLService.h file you have to change '#define GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER 1' to '#define GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER 0'

Here's where I found my answer: [GTMSessionFetcher.h file not found upgrading app to latest google-api-objectivec-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822629/gtmsessionfetcher-h-file-not-found-upgrading-app-to-latest-google-api-objectivec)

Note:
This may not be a google-drive-sdk issue, It can be an issue with xcode library handling, cocoapods or library management of the project wasn't configured properly.